# Create a dictionary in c# through lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a following code:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<byte?, List<Id>>();
foreach (var record in Records)
{
    if(record.SubId.HasValue)
    {
        dict.Add(SubIdsDictionary[record.SubId.Value], new List<Record> { record });
    }
    else
    {
        dict.Add(IdsDictionary[record.Id.Value], new List<Record> { record });
    }
}
```

Records is the list of records for one name.In this record class I have Id,SubId and Companyname. Each name have id as mandatory but subid is not.So,if name has subid then I have to give priority to subid and first get the new sub id from the dictionary SubIdsDictionary(because subid is key in ref dict SubIdsDictionary) and make the new subid as key and the whole record as value in the new Dictionary **dict**. But if name dont have subid then i will use id and first get the new id from reference dict  IdsDictionary and make the new id as key and value will be whole record.
Now in the new dictionary keys will be mix of ids and subids and record will be value as List

Can someone help me to convert this code through lambda?

Comment: Any help????????

Comment: `Dictionary<byte?, List<Id>>()` i think you canot have a dictionary key null, to populate your `new List<type>`use "(", not "{"

Comment: @CelsoLívero `new List<T>{ aT, anotherT } ` is perfectly valid. It's a collection initializer.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ToDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb548657(v=vs.110).aspx) method from Linq.

It should looks like this:

```
 var dict = Records.ToDictionary(
    r => (r.SubId.HasValue ? SubIdsDictionary[r.SubId.Value] : IdsDictionary[r.Id.Value]), 
    r => new List<Record> {r}
 );
```